# POV and Grammatical Person tags

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Should we turn the [pov](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pov) into a synonym of the [grammatical-person](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammatical-person) tag? For the purposes of this site, I think they're more or less the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Not necessarily, since imho the PoV tag covers a larger set of questions.

People may ask of the difference on using a third person, omniscent narrator, rather than a third person unreliable one.

They're both third-person PoVs, but they are different, and the grammatical-person doesn't really come into play since it's more about the use and the characteristics of the PoV.